# MSI: How to speed up ExecuteAction

Tags: windows-installer

In my current MSI [ExecuteAction](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa368565(v=VS.85).aspx) takes at least 1m 30s. I created a simple msi (from WiX examples) and it takes about 4 seconds for ExecuteAction.

How can I optimize my MSI package, so ExecuteAction will run faster?

Comment: Use msiexec to output a log file, and pastebin it here.

Answer (score 10):

Windows uses ExecuteAction to initiate a [system restore point](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa372060%28VS.85%29.aspx). Depending on your machine configuration, this can take quite a while. During performance testing our company's installer, we encountered elapsed times of 5 to 26 seconds.

Windows XP, it seems, by default, does not create system restore points. Windows Vista and Windows 7, however, do. Here are our test results over 24 machines (averages):

- Windows XP: 1 second
- Windows Vista: 7 seconds
- Windows 7: 13 seconds

There is a workaround for Windows 7 (in Windows Installer 5). [Here is the MSDN article.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd408005%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)
The workaround is to disable the system restore point for the installer.
Here is the workaround in WiX:

```
<Property Id="MSIFASTINSTALL" Value="1"/>
```

[Here is another example of the same problem as yours](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/winformssetup/thread/2bf77b98-c36c-4b92-baa5-69872fd3b6ce?prof=required) where I found the solution.