# Why does the UAC dialog take a long time to be displayed?

Tags: deployment, wix, windows-installer, installation, wix3.5

I am working on a Windows installer using the WIX toolkit, and it takes FOR EVER (15-45 seconds) for the UAC dialog to pop up during an install. is there any way to speed this up?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Everytime you install software using Windows Installer, a restore point is created prior to do the actual installation. Ref: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa372060.aspx

You can turn this off in the registry: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa369758.aspx

Comment: My guess is also that it's the creation of a restore point that is your problem. Try reading this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6866634/600559

Answer (score 8):

Thanks to joegrage for pointing me in the right direction on this one.  The trick to this seems to be the `MSIFASTINSTALL` property.

The `MSIFASTINSTALL` property can be used to reduce the time required to install a large Windows Installer package. The property can be set on the command line or in the Property table to configure operations that the user or developer determines are non-essential for the installation.

The value of the MSIFASTINSTALL property can be a combination of the following values.

```
value  Meaning 
-----  -----------------------------------------------------------
0      Default value
1      No system restore point is saved for this installation.
2      Perform only File Costing and skip checking other costs.
4      Reduce the frequency of progress messages.
```

In WIX, you can use a combination of these values like so:

```
<Property Id="MSIFASTINSTALL" Value="3" />
```

A more detailed write up about this property can be found on [this](http://community.saasgrid.com/developers/b/team/archive/2011/02/17/wix-managed-custom-actions-openfiledialog-example.aspx) blog post.

Comment: The referenced link is dead :(

Comment: @GTAE86 Removed link.  The text contained in the post was copied verbatim from the MSDN page, so all you need to know is in the post already.

Answer (score 5):

This happens because Windows is checking if the package has a digital signature.

Unfortunately the digital signature verification algorithm is not very good. Also, its performance depends on the package size. So a bigger package will have a longer delay.

To avoid the delay you can add a simple EXE bootstrapper to your MSI. It’s purpose is to request elevation through an [application manifest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb756929.aspx) and launch the MSI next to it. If you don’t include your MSI in it, the bootstrapper will have a small size. So the digital signature check will be very fast.

Comment: I'll give this a try and see how it goes.